# Unable to select same item twice in a CollectionView with Command NO EVENT

Tags: xamarin, command, collectionview

I am not able to select an item twice. I don't use events. I manage everything with commands and the ViewModel.
I can just find solutions for the Code Behind.

CodeBehind Solution
((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

I don't use a sender, so this variant doesn't work.

Here is my CommandCall:

```xml
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Single"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Lib:Profile_Model}}, 
                                       Path=UserPartyById}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Profile_Party_DataTemplate}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Lib:Profile_Model}}, 
                                      Path=SelectedItem}"

                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Lib:Profile_Model}}, 
                                      Path=GoPartyDetailCommand}">

    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

</CollectionView>
```

```cs
GoPartyDetailCommand = new Command(GoPartyDetail);

private Merged_Model selectedItem;
public Merged_Model SelectedItem
{
    get => selectedItem;
    set => SetPorperty(ref selectedItem, value);
}

public async void GoPartyDetail()
{
    Preferences.Set("SelectPartyId", SelectedItem.Id);
    Preferences.Set("FK_User", SelectedItem.FK_User);
    await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<PartyDetail_ViewModel>();
}
```

H

Comment: there is not enough code here to show what is actually happening?  What CollectionView command are you using?  What is your SelectionMode set to?

Comment: the SelectionChange command does not fire if the same item is selected twice.  That is why it is recommended that you clear the SelectedItem property.

Comment: I guess is enough code but i update it now with my collectionview.
Yeah i try to clear it but if i set the SelectedItem property to null after first select there throw me a NullException

Comment: then you need to track down the exception and fix it

Answer (score 0):

The expected behavior for SelectionChanged is correct - it doesn't get fired if you select the same item twice since the selectedItem is already selected. The only way to fire SelectionChanged is to either (1) select a different item before selecting the item again, or (2) setting the selected item to null, But before making it to null put some delay. I tried with 500 ms and it worked.

Please refer the  link
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11405

```
await Task.Delay(5000); 
RecommandedAttendeesList.SelectedItem = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Maverick stated you can set the SelectedItem to null, but in my case as soon as I would set it to null it would fire the SelectionChanged event again. My fix (using MVVM, but should work with codebehind too) is to do a null check and if so return.

```
        private async void ExecuteSelectionChanged(object item)
        {
            if(SelectedItem == null){ return; }
              [ your code logic ]
            SelectedItemLog = null;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `SelectionChangedCommandParameter` to pass your `ColletionView` to your viewmodel,then you could use clean the `SelectedItem`.

```
<CollectionView
     x:Name = "collectionview"
     SelectionMode="Single"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Lib:Profile_Model}}, 
                               Path=UserPartyById}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Profile_Party_DataTemplate}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Lib:Profile_Model}}, 
                              Path=SelectedItem}"

     SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Lib:Profile_Model}},Path=GoPartyDetailCommand}"   
     SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{x:Reference collectionview}"
        >

        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="5" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

</CollectionView>
```

then in your viewmodel:

```
public ICommand GoPartyDetailCommand => new Command<CollectionView>(GoPartyDetail);

public async void GoPartyDetail(CollectionView collectionview)
{
   // you could get the collectionview,then clean the selectItem
    Preferences.Set("SelectPartyId", SelectedItem.Id);
    Preferences.Set("FK_User", SelectedItem.FK_User);
    await _navigationService.NavigateToAsync<PartyDetail_ViewModel>();

}
```

Comment: In **MVVM** framework, **ViewModel** is ignorant of the XAML Page and the Code Behind it. That means **ViewModel** does not know View page or Code Behind it, including its fields, objects and properties.