# Cant reselect previous selected item in CollectionView in Xamarin.Forms on iOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

### TLDR

CollectionView broken in iOS, cant find any solution online. Weak Google fu or just not seeing the answer.

### The problem

I have a CollectionView (Lets call it A) that contains items that are only strings values for filtering on a different CollectionView (Lets call it B) containing results from selecting a filter option in CollectionView A.

I have 3 different filtering options: "All", "Close to you", "Online" in CollectionView A.

The problem is that on iOS when I select for example filter option "All" in CollectionView A for the first time on the page it does the filtering and shows the results in CollectionView B, when I choose for example filtering option "Online" in CollectionView A it filters and shows the results in CollectionView B.

But when I choose filtering option "All" for the second time in CollectionView A its not responding, no event triggers, no commands runs and its not disabled. It is only showing, but I cant do anything with it.

### Expected result

Can reselect the previous item on iOS, in Android no problem.

### Actual result

Cant reselect previous item on iOS, need to back to previous page in stack and then navigate back to page to reset filtering.

### The xaml markup

This is the xaml markup for the CollectionView A as explained above, the only holding string values to filter on.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding FilterLocations}"
                Grid.Row="2"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilterLocation}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                HeightRequest="50">
   <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
      <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         ItemSpacing="10" />
   </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
      <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <StackLayout xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True">
               <Frame BorderColor="{StaticResource BorderColor}"
                      x:Name="subCategoryFrame"
                      Padding="14, 10">
                  <Label Text="{Binding .}"
                         x:Name="subCategoryName"
                         FontFamily="{StaticResource FontPoppinsLight}"
                         TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryAlt}" />
               </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
         </DataTemplate>
      </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <CollectionView.Header>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="0"
                     HeightRequest="1"
                     BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
         </CollectionView.Header>
         <CollectionView.Footer>
            <BoxView WidthRequest="{StaticResource NormalSpacingDouble}"
                     HeightRequest="1"
                     BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
         </CollectionView.Footer>
      </CollectionView>
```

The CollectionView A is in SelectionMode:Single, and the SelectedItem is bound to a ICommand on its bound ViewModel. And in the ViewModel the selection of a item in CollectionView A will trigger a filtering in CollectionView B

### What I done so far

I set up so if a item in the CollectionView A is disabled it become Red, but it dont become Red.

I have tried to add a event in the Code behind, to try and set SelectedItem to null, but that back fired and just made all events go twice, one for selecting the item on the screen and second for altering the SelectedItem in the code behind.

Code:

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
      if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
      {
         var collectionView = sender as CollectionView;
         if (collectionView == null) return;

         if (collectionView.SelectedItem != null)
         {
             collectionView.SelectedItem = null;
         }
      }
}
```

(I know it is a big no no to do logic stuff in the Code Behind that is not design logic, but I need to get this solved or have a quick and dirty fix because of time pressure.)

Sorry for the wall of text

Comment: can you explain clearly what your problem? if you want to select  PreviousSelection in the collection view , you can simply add var prev =  e.PreviousSelection; in your CollectionView_SelectionChanged function

Comment: @AmjadS. I dont want the previous selection, I want to be able to select item 1, then select item 2 and the select 1 again. But the second press on item 1 wont get any response, no event fire of or Commands is getting run.

Comment: you have a mistake in your event function. i fixed it in my answer

Comment: Refer the link for the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71512642/1069783

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `TapGestureRecognizer`.

Below, `MyItemCommand` is defined in `MyViewModel` and `{Binding .}` refers to the item selected in `ItemsSource`.

```
<DataTemplate ...>
  <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MyViewModel}},
                                              Path=MyItemCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    ...
```

Comment: I detected that I was wrong that "SelectedItem" was bound to a command, it was bound to a property. But reworked it to a ICommand and everthing worked like a charm. 
Thank you! 
Now I have the problem that iOS dont add the selected highlight on it, but I can fix that on my own.

Answer (score 0):

First Bind the collection view into the event selectionchange.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding FilterLocations}"
                Grid.Row="2"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilterLocation}"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                HeightRequest="50"
                SelectionChanged="collection_SelectionChanged">
```

then inside the event put selected item to null.

```
private async void collection_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      var Sender = sender as CollectionView;
      if (Sender.SelectedItem == null)
          return;
                
       Sender.SelectedItem = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

     }
}
```

Comment: The problem I had did not resolve because of this, already tried this and lead down to wierd behavior for me. But thanks for submitting :)